# iOS: How to add toolbar or any footer below Table View?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, cs193p

I've followed the CS193p introduction course to objective C. I have now a grouped Table View, and my view controller is a CoreDataTableViewController (from the CS193p class), which is basically just a subclass of UITableViewController with the FetchedResultsControllerDelegate implemented. In my app there are several screens connected, so if you press one row in the first table you get to a new screen with all the subcategories for that main category etc. All the screens are subclasses of this CoreDataViewController.

I'm now confused about how to add a toolbar at the very bottom of a screen in one particular Table View. I guess I have to insert a new view in which I include a table view and a toolbar. What I don't understand how to hookup everything so the whole TableView actually works? Before the very "top" controller was my CoreDataTableViewController (which I've subclassed and implemented my own methods), but now I have no idea how to continue? How do I get the values from the parent view controller to this embedded table view controller and further to his child view controller later on?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a navigation based application you can set up a toolbar by calling:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```